# remove whitespaces tail from string (char*)

Tags: c, string, file, removing-whitespace

hello I've got text file with lines format

```
1|few ewf ew fewfew
```

I need to parse it but I don't know how can I drop whitespaces tail from second value I don't know.

Here is my `segmentation fault` try so far

```
char* token1;
char* token2;
char* search = "|";
char* search2 = "  "; // double space because string can contains single space
while (fgets(line, 150, f)) {
  token1 = strtok(line, search);
  token2 = strtok(search, search2); // <- segfault
  //token2 = strtok(NULL, search); <- contains a lot of spaces in tail
```

Comment: Use [`rtrim()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimming_(computer_programming)#C.2FC.2B.2B)?

Comment: `strtok` modifies the string passed as the first argument. Your variable `search` points to a constant string that cannot be modified. Thus you get a *segmentation fault*.

Comment: @Crozin please provide it as answer )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a gander at the `deblank` function.  Here's a link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deblank.html