# Place words of a string into an array of strings - c programming

Tags: c, arrays, string, string.h

I am trying to get a function to split a string containing several words which are separated by 1 or more spaces and put each word without any spaces into an index of an array of strings.

I have been googling it for a while, it seems I need strtok but I am a bit clueless, would someone please shed some light?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582955/remove-whitespaces-tail-from-string-char

Comment: not really, I am not looking to remove white spaces, I am more concerned about obtaining the words

Answer (score 4):

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you @andro1d this a good start. Am I able to tell strtok to ignore \n and \t?

Eg.: - This, a sample \t string. to produce outcome:
-
This,
a
sample
string

Comment: As it is right now it places the \t alone in a line. thank you :)